# VS2005 SQL Syntax highlighting is incorrect for nested comments?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, syntax-highlighting, ssms

I'm working with VS2005, and SSMS 2005.

SQL Server allows nested comments as follows:

```
/* Comment 1
/* Comment 2 */
Some commented out code here
*/
```

This code runs fine. However if putting the above into a .sql file in VS2005, it incorrectly shows the commented out code as 'active', (its not green). It seems that  StackOverflow has highlighted the code in the same way.

Is this a bug in VS2005? Or does SSMS handle nested comments differently compared to the ANSI SQL standards?

Can someone clarify this discrepancy, and if it appears to be a bug, if there a way to fix the syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this in SSMS 2008 and VS2010 and it is all green so I would guess it is a bug in VS2005?